# How do I assign the correct ID to my y_pred?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a `pd.Dataframe` dataset with columns:

```
index, text, label, ID
```

The ID is given in a specific way, so that the texts can be assigned into groups by ID.
I Preprocessed the Text, made a `Pipeline`, did a `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` and predicted using gridsearch(`gs.fit(x_train,y_train)`).
Now I have my **original dataset, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test** and **y_pred.** Where y_pred is `y_pred = gs_fit.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)`.

*Here's what I want:*

I want to now find out the corresponding ID's of my y_pred's to see if there are some groups from the ID's that were better predicted than others.

My problem here is, that I don't have the index anymore, the text is different after preprocessing and because of that I am not sure how I can **find out which y_pred is connected to which ID**.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `index` is preserved. `X_test.index == y_test.index`

```py
# ... assumes you split your DataFrame and no resetting of index

X, y = df[['feature_1','feature_2']], df[['target']]

# train_size or test_size
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, train_size=.8, random_state=42)

# index is kept. So the 
print(all(X_test.index == y_test.index)) # True
```

So just use index to locate the ID. The `y_pred` will be ordered in the same appearance of X_test.index.

```
# return only test IDs and their predictions
results = df[df.index == X_test.index][['ID']]
results['y_pred'] = y_pred
print(results)
```

If `index` is lost due to use of another data structure than Pandas, then another trick is to pre-append the `ID` onto text `AC123 | text input here`. Your text function would have to exclude all text prior to `|`. Do whatever text preprocessing with the latter. You can then use the first part to lookup the ID